# Is learning to make iOS apps from iOS Programming (The Big Nerd Ranch, 4th Edition) a good idea now?

Tags: ios, xcode

So the story is, my friend has given me a copy of iOS Programming (The Big Nerd Ranch, 4th Edition). The book uses Xcode 5 and iOS 7. Now that Xcode 6 and iOS 8 is here, would it be wrong of me to learn from this book, and will the concepts be relevant to the new Xcode/iOS, or will it be too outdated and obsolete.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: The next Xcode and iOS 9 will come in beta on Monday.

Comment: Why don't you get a free Swift book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode 5 and iOS 7 is still pretty relevant, and the fundamentals haven't changed. There will be some differences in the specifics, and features of iOS that won't be covered (e.g. widgets) but most of those things would be more at the intermediate/advanced level. For the fundamentals, you should be fine with that book. Note the book will not cover Swift at all, which might be a better language to start learning, instead of Objective C. Depends on what you need to learn.

I would suggest finding other free online tutorials / books / videos to supplement your learning as you go along as well.